# Are Bollywood actors actually filming 30 to 40 films at any one time?

Tags: acting, indian-cinema

In this interview

Aamir Khan says most Bollywood actors are filming at various stages 30 to 40 films at any one time. Is this true and the norm in Bollywood?

Comment: I watched the clip - and wanted to clarify that he's claiming many actors are in the process of filming 30-40 films at the same time.  Just wanted to clarify that it wasn't just that they sign up for 30-40 films in the future.

Comment: Probably not intentionally or consciously, I'd think, but they probably slice and dice footage across as many films as they can, kind of like the porn industry.

Comment: @poloholeset are you serious? LOL

Comment: @newguy - Yes. Apparently some adult stars show up in hundreds of titles, and I heard one complaining that she was paid for a handful of shoots, but then appeared in so many more by reusing the same footage, or different camera angles of the same scenes, but she didn't get additional pay. Don't know if they still do that, or if the actors are more savvy about how they structure their compensation these days. I don't actually follow the industry that closely (probably the mantra of every perv who is obsessed with porn, but I gotta put that disclaimer out there).

Comment: Unfortunately, the embedded video is now unavailable. This question now lacks context for it to be answerable. Due to that, I'm voting to close this question as "needs details or clarity".

Comment: @galacticninja The claim that Aamir Khan made is included in the body of the question, which makes the question itself understandable even without the video.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm unable to find a source for the claim in this question. I tried googling it, and was led back to this question. `@Stupid_Intern Would you be able to provide a source for the claim? If not, I believe this question should be closed as "Needs details or clarity."

Comment: Is [this the same interview](https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,524538,00.html)? In it, he says some actors were filmed in 30-40 movies **per year**, not all at once.